# Read the last ID# on database and prevent duplication when creating new row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database which is frequently updated by the main script which is php encrypted and i can't read or edit it

I need to have another script separately which can also add a row at the end of the table with a new ID and it shouldn't duplicate with id's created by the main script, (the other script could have been updated within or a few seconds after that i've read ID)

**So, How can i read the latest ID column value, and then create a new row for this purpose?**

**it doesn't matter if in my new script, ID# is increased with +2 or even +5, because the main script always reads the last ID and makes it +1**

i just don't one them to make the same ID at the same time

Comment: Are you sure that it's not using an auto_increment field? No decent software designer would create an ID by selecting the highest one and adding 1.

Comment: We will hope not, but sometimes id's are alphanumeric, so auto-increment may not work.

Comment: If IDs are alphanumeric, then you should have two columns: one for the alpha part and an autoincrement one for the numeric part

Comment: no i didn't knew how it works, so i suppose its using auto_increment field is you've said, i thought it creates ID by adding 1 to the highest, thank you for teaching me this guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any trickery here, just set the ID column to be `PRIMARY` and `AUTO_INCREMENT`, this will mean MySQL will assign the next available int to your row, and allow the old script to insert whatever it wants, avoiding collisions.

More info on that here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html